# How to download entire OneDrive folder in python

Tags: python

I have a microsoft One Drive folder that was shared publicly. I am wondering how to download all the contents using python.

I do not own the folder. It's just a public folder.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python):

```
root_folder = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children.get()
id_of_file = root_folder[0].id

client.item(drive='me', id=id_of_file).download('./path_to_download_to.txt')
```